# Ember.JS + Require.JS — Rendering specific view depending on the route

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, javascript-framework

I'm trying out Ember.JS and I'm having a **really tough time** using it with Require.JS so far, even with a (pretty) basic example.

First of all, I'd like to say that Require.JS is supposed to (I think) improve two weak points I see in Ember.JS :

- Organizing the app, especially in separate js files
- Not loading unnecessary code

I'm basically trying to display an app with header/content/footer. So, when I'm creating my App I'm binding a ApplicationController and an ApplicationView, and the view handles the template. This works great in displaying (pretty easily) the header and the footer.

Then, I'm trying to render a template for the index (for example), and I would like to **dynamically** load IndexView/IndexController (for example) and bind it with a route. That's where I'm having a tough time.

I found an easy way to do this by setting IndexView directly as App.IndexView, but the problem with this solution is that if I load IndexView, I'm also loading the index template file content (using text.js plugin). That would be okay for my example, BUT since I'm trying to build a complex website, that would mean loading all the templates when loading the website, which is exactly what Require.JS was trying to avoid.

**Where am I wrong here?** How do I dynamically load the template depending on the routing?

Comment: Have you looked at the native [Ember Router](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/). It seems like it would solve your problem completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: It's not really needed to declare a placeholder in the main html document as it's injected using view.append().

I've been struggling with the same thing, and I finally came up with a way to split over router, controller, views and templates loading them dynamically.

This is my main "embermain.js" file:

```
window.MyRanks = Ember.Application.create();

MyRanks.Router.map(
    function() {
        this.route('about');
    }
);

MyRanks.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        require(['app/controller/AboutController'], function(controller) {
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my AboutController:

```
require(
    ['app/view/AboutView'],
    function (view) {
        var controller = MyRanks.AboutController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        });
        return controller;
    });
```

Here is my AboutView:

```
define(
    ['text!app/templates/about.html'],
    function (template) {
        var view = Ember.View.create({
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(template),
            templateName: 'about',
            variable: 'my value',
            didInsertElement: function() {
                console.log( "Yes the view was included");
            }
        });
        view.append();
        return view;
    }
);
```

And here is the template about.html

```
This is the template {{view.variable}}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer ! I actually learnt a while back when I asked the same question on #emberjs that RequireJS is a bad practice with EmberJS, mostly because one big file is better than a lot of asynchronous calls.

Comment: Right now it is making sense here, I'm using yeoman and it's preset grunt build tasks just end up mixing it all into an uglyfied big js file which makes all my efforts useless. But in the other hand, it's not that I don't like it, and it's definitely not my case, but what if it was a huge app which would result into a single js file weighting several megabytes, would that be the best approach?

Comment: I thought the same, but in the end my file is more or less 40ko, so I think maybe in really really really rare cases it might be useful to use RequireJS, but most of the time it's not.